# How to make better lines?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

So I'm making a paint app in C# and it works by marking a point when the user clicks on the paint panel, then while the user has his/her mouse down drawing a line when the mouse is moved to the new position; I'm learning C# so its pretty basic. Now everything's fine until I size up the pen, when I do that the lines start to look super weird? Does anyone know any possible solutions to make the line look normal?

[image: Weird Lines]

here's my code, I'm using a windows form app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace paintApplication
{

    public partial class frmPaintApp : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// variables
        /// </summary>
        bool shouldPaint = false;
        Point prePoint;
        float penSize = 1;
        Graphics g;

        ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();

        public frmPaintApp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            g = pnlPaintPanel.CreateGraphics();
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        }

        private void msPensize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (float.TryParse(msTxtchoosesize.Text , out penSize))
            {
                msTxtchoosesize.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private void pnlPaintPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            shouldPaint = true;
            prePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }

        private void pnlPaintPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            shouldPaint = false;
        }

        private void pnlPaintPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen p = new Pen(cd.Color, penSize);


            if (shouldPaint == true)
            {
                g.DrawLine(p, prePoint, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }

            prePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

        }

        private void msChoosecolor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cd.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void frmPaintApp_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            g = pnlPaintPanel.CreateGraphics();
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        }

        private void msClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            g.Clear(pnlPaintPanel.BackColor);

        }

        private void msExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void pnlPaintPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Painting circles instead of lines would help.

Comment: Never store that graphic object — it's temporary.  Never use CreateGraphics.  Use the paint event of your panel to draw all your lines or use a bitmap and show that in the paint event.  Are you trying to use a pen size of 45?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Agreed. One could bind the size of the circle to the size of the 'pen' in the paint program. A solid fill on a variable size 'pen' which draws circles should do exactly what is wanted.

Comment: Why not use a GraphicsPath to create the path and set the lineJoin to round

Comment: There are DrawLines and DrawCurve methods that will avoid all sorts or artifacts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides my comments regarding using CreateGraphics, etc, try changing your LineCaps (and dispose of your pen, you're leaking memory):

```
using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, penSize)) {
  p.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
  p.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
  if (shouldPaint) {
    g.DrawLine(p, prePoint, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
  }
}
```